# Using a variable in a manual colour palette

Tags: r

I've got a variable called Team

```
Team <- "Denver"
```

I want to then use this in my manual colour scheme.

```
colours.manual <- c(Team = "green", "Draw" = "grey", "Other Team" = "red")
```

The problem here is that my colours.manual assigns green to Team instead of Denver.

What do I need to do so I use the variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `setNames`

```
colours.manual <- setNames(c("green", "grey", "red"), c(Team, "Draw", "Other Team"))
colours.manual
#     Denver       Draw Other Team 
#    "green"     "grey"      "red"
```

Comment: Excellent. That worked. So essentially, I am assigning each colour a name by using the setNames function? I was previously doing this with the equal operator but this method didn't allow the use of a variable.

Is this correct?

Comment: @user1923975 Yes, setNames assigns the names to each element. It can be useful where you want to pass variables and also strings.